# I m trying to make my Nodehandle global,below is my code.But I m unable to listen to subscribed topic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m trying to make my Nodehandle global,below is my code.But I m unable to listen to subscribed topic

```
#include<ros/ros.h>
        #include<tf/transform_listener.h>
        #include<std_msgs/Float32.h>

        using namespace std;

        class Node{
            private:
                ros::NodeHandle nh;
            public:
                Node(ros::NodeHandle &nh){
                    this->nh=nh;
                }
                ros::NodeHandle getnh(){
                    return this->nh;
                }
        };

        void dataRecevied(const::std_msgs::Float32::ConstPtr &msg){
            ROS_INFO("yes3");
            ROS_INFO("Range is %f",msg->data);
        }

        void turn(Node n){
            ros::NodeHandle nh=n.getnh();
            ros::Subscriber sub;
            ROS_INFO("yes2");
            sub=nh.subscribe("test1",1,dataRecevied);

        }

        int main(int argv,char **argc){
            ros::init(argv,argc,"tf_listener");
            ros::NodeHandle nh;
            Node pub(nh);
            ROS_INFO("yes1");
            turn(pub);
            ros::spin();
        }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330706/i-m-trying-to-make-my-nodehandle-global,below-is-my-code.but-i-m-unable-to-listen-to-subscribed-topic./) by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem with your subscriber is not related to the node handles, although I'll get to that later.

Your subscriber will only function while the `sub` object exists, since you declare it as a local variable in the `turn()` method as soon as that function finishes the subscriber is destroyed. This is the reason why you're not receiving any messages.

I would recommend putting everything into your class and storing the subscriber as a private member of the class.

Node handles are slightly unusual in that they always behave as the same object whenever you create them, so there is no point storing and passing a node handle object, because any code can create a new node handle and it will behave exactly the same way.

If you move all your ROS code into the class then your constructor would create a nodeHandle as usual, and use it to create the subscriber.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) on 2019-08-15**:
Thank You,your method works..But I have two doubt now,first is that I dont have to declare my NodeHandle global whenever I want to use NodeHandle outside the main function I will just create a new one and it will work fine isnt it?

My second doubt is little out of box and silly..What is the use of OOPs when we are just creating a ros Node isnt the main function and the callback functions are sufficient.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-08-15**:
Your first point is correct, you can create a new nodeHandle object whenever you need one.

Your second point is a big question. You can do everything in ROS without using OOP, but it does get tidier for larger projects to use it. Some would say it's a matter of taste, others would say its the more efficient way of engineering large projects.

**Comment by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) on 2019-08-15**:
Okay.thnaks